# iOS Encode String From JSON API

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, encoding

I am downloading data from an API in JSON using `NSURLConnection` and `NSJSONSerialization`. The JSON is returning all `&` as in the HTML ampersand literal: `&amp;`.

I'm wondering if that's supposed to be encoded properly on the server, with UTF-8 to Unicode, and received by me as `&` or if I'm supposed to be doing that work.

Here is the code I use to download the data:

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:api_url]];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:queue
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
                               NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                               // do work
                           }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe there is a requirement in the `JSON` spec for it to be one way or the other.  When I am personally working with an `API` that I have control over, I like that sort of work to be done on the server side (better yet, I prefer to keep view stuff like `HTML` markup out of the data in the first place).

Comment: In my case, the API is not encoding the characters properly, correct? Should the API be encoding using UTF-8 for me to receive the correct `&` character? The data has no HTML markup so I'm not sure why the API developer has this `&amp;`.

Comment: Correct, JSON is supposed to be unicode.  The API could just include the & character instead of the escaped HTML &amp; character sequence.  I would assume it was returning &amp; because the content was/is being consumed by a web application that presented the content directly.

Answer (score 0):

JSON must be encoded in some Unicode format. The format can be UTF-8, UTF-16 big-endian or little-endian, or UTF-32 big-endian or little-endian. Characters in JSON strings can be encoded like \u007f for example, but if there are any & characters then that is the data that the server wants to send you. For example, a server could send a string containing html or a URL, and you would receiver that string with & characters and all.